# Haskell: Using `cabal test` for integration tests with code coverage

Tags: haskell, integration-testing, cabal

Setup: .cabal file with library, executable that depends on the library and a test-suite. The test-suite calls integration test written in python. However, that gives me empty coverage reports from `cabal test`. I think that's because python calls the executable not the test-suite?

Questions

1. What is the difference between "Package coverage report" and the "Test coverage report"?
2. Should I call the test-suite binary from python, where the test-suite has a flag such that it behaves like the executable?

Comment: Turns out that idea 2. does not work. I have opened https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3902 and removed the integration tests from cabal.